# Error java.net.URISyntaxException when SBT compile update

Tags: scala, sbt

I have tried to compile custom module in spark. When I used sbt version 1.5.8 I had no problems, but when I used sbt version 1.9.2 I got the following error：

```
[error] java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 98: http://maven.baidu-int.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/baidu/rpc/baidu-rpc-pb25/1.0.13.35408/${baidu-rpc.artifactId}-1.0.13.35408.jar
[error]     at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2873)
[error]     at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3046)
[error]     at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3130)
[error]     at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3078)
[error]     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
[error]     at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:989)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JavaExtraFormats.$anonfun$urlStringIso$1(JavaExtraFormats.scala:40)
[error]     at sjsonnew.IsoString$$anon$1.to(IsoString.scala:26)
[error]     at sjsonnew.IsoFormats$$anon$2.write(IsoFormats.scala:31)
[error]     at sjsonnew.StandardFormats$OptionFormat.write(StandardFormats.scala:37)
[error]     at sjsonnew.StandardFormats$OptionFormat.addField(StandardFormats.scala:44)
[error]     at sjsonnew.StandardFormats$OptionFormat.addField(StandardFormats.scala:33)
[error]     at sjsonnew.Builder.addField(Builder.scala:43)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ArtifactFormats$$anon$1.write(ArtifactFormats.scala:36)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ArtifactFormats$$anon$1.write(ArtifactFormats.scala:9)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2$adapted(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField(JsonFormat.scala:40)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField$(JsonFormat.scala:37)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.addField(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.Builder.addField(Builder.scala:43)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleReportFormats$$anon$1.write(ModuleReportFormats.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleReportFormats$$anon$1.write(ModuleReportFormats.scala:9)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2$adapted(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField(JsonFormat.scala:40)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField$(JsonFormat.scala:37)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.addField(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.Builder.addField(Builder.scala:43)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ConfigurationReportFormats$$anon$1.write(ConfigurationReportFormats.scala:26)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ConfigurationReportFormats$$anon$1.write(ConfigurationReportFormats.scala:9)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.$anonfun$write$2$adapted(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
[error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:85)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.write(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField(JsonFormat.scala:40)
[error]     at sjsonnew.JsonWriter.addField$(JsonFormat.scala:37)
[error]     at sjsonnew.CollectionFormats$$anon$2.addField(CollectionFormats.scala:80)
[error]     at sjsonnew.Builder.addField(Builder.scala:43)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.UpdateReportFormats$$anon$1.write(UpdateReportFormats.scala:27)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.UpdateReportFormats$$anon$1.write(UpdateReportFormats.scala:9)
[error]     at sjsonnew.SupportConverter.toJsonUnsafe(SupportConverter.scala:23)
[error]     at sjsonnew.SupportConverter.toJsonUnsafe$(SupportConverter.scala:20)
[error]     at sjsonnew.support.scalajson.unsafe.Converter$.toJsonUnsafe(Converter.scala:7)
[error]     at sjsonnew.SupportConverter.$anonfun$toJson$1(SupportConverter.scala:14)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
[error]     at sjsonnew.SupportConverter.toJson(SupportConverter.scala:14)
[error]     at sjsonnew.SupportConverter.toJson$(SupportConverter.scala:13)
[error]     at sjsonnew.support.scalajson.unsafe.Converter$.toJson(Converter.scala:7)
[error]     at sbt.util.FileOutput.write(Output.scala:39)
[error]     at sbt.util.FileBasedStore.write(CacheStore.scala:90)
[error]     at sbt.internal.InMemoryCacheStore$CacheStoreImpl.write(InMemoryCacheStore.scala:76)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:75)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:147)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:147)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:128)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:220)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:161)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3799)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:63)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:69)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:283)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:24)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:292)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:283)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:65)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[error] (yarn-baidu / update) java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 98: http://maven.baidu-int.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/baidu/rpc/baidu-rpc-pb25/1.0.13.35408/${baidu-rpc.artifactId}-1.0.13.35408.jar
```

I checked my SparkBuild.scala, plugin.sbt and pom.xml, No configuration of ${bidu-rpc.artifactid} variable found, I think this URI is generated by sbt plugin. However, the configuration file does not change when using different versions of sbt.

Is this an sbt bug in 1.9.2? (I guess)

Comment: By the way, I have tested several versions of sbt and they all compile successfully with the same code and configuration at least before 1.8.3.

Comment: could you share your `build.sbt`? is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: sure, I only changed SparkBuild.scala. Added yarn-baidu in allProjects which in object BuildCommons.